# How to deal with nested static casting?

Tags: java, casting, hashmap

I simply have a `Map`. But it can return a `Map`, which may also return a `Map`. It's possible up to 3 to 4 nested `Map`s. So when I want to access a nested value, I need to do this:

```
((Map)((Map)((Map)CacheMap.get("id")).get("id")).get("id")).get("id")
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

The reason I'm using a `Map` instead of mapping it to an object is for maintainability (e.g. when there are new fields).

**Note:**

`Map<String, Object>`

It has to be `Object` because it won't always return a `Hashmap`. It may return a `String` or a `Long`.

**Further clarification:**

What I'm doing is I'm calling an api which returns a `json` response which I save as a `Map`.

Comment: You should not use such a complex class structure at all in the first place. It is too complex, hard to understand and error-prone. Instead, create custom classes reflecting your actual structure. What type of data are you storing? Why do you have 4 ids? For example, instead of having a Map representing houses containing families, containing humans - create those classes, `House`, `Family`, `Human` and then have a `List<House>` with a `getFamilies()` etc. And even if you need such a generic nested map, at least create a class for it. `NestedMap` with a `get` method that accepts multiple keys.

Comment: Generics were introduced 14 years ago, and you're still using raw types... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html. Your code is completely unmaintainable **because** you're using Maps instead of well-defined, type-safe, encapsulated, discoverable, refactorable classes.

Comment: Whatever you are doing there, this is not what i call "maintainability"

Comment: @Zabuza the ids are just an example.

Oh okay. I thought this was maintainable since if there were changes to the json response i'm saving as a map, then i wouldn't need to create new fields and getters and setters.

Comment: What's the problem with creating new fields, getters and setters? Once you have done that, which takes 5 seconds, all your code knows that this class now has a new property (you can't know that with a Map), how to access it (you can't know that with a Map) and what its type is (you can't know that with a Map). The IDE autosuggests and autocompletes the method calls (you can't do that with a Map). If you want to make it readonly, you can just avoid the setter (you can't do that with a Map). Do I need to continue?

Comment: Aight I'll be using proper classes instead. All of you, thanks for correcting me!

Comment: @JBNizet It's untrue that *"your code is completely unmaintainable because blah blah"*. As it happens, I designed and deployed code very like OP's idea to production for a major company, and it performs superbly, is very easy to maintain and test, and is it still in use today. I also implemented a DSL to traverse the structure, which proved very productive to use by clients. Further, it could not have been done with "well-defined, type-safe, encapsulated, discoverable, refactorable classes" as there would have been hundreds of them and they changed constantly, which is **not** maintainable.

Comment: `and they changed constantly`

Thanks @Bohemian.

This was the reason why I wanted to use a `Map`. If I were to go with classes, I'd have to add a field or change *the entire structure* of the class which could affect **a lot**. Whereas with a `Map`, I'd just have to change the `key` in `Map#get(key)`.

So now I've actually started mapping them to classes. Though I'm still in constant worry that whenever the entire json structure changes, then the entire class changes - which means refactoring ***existing*** fields, getters, setters, constructors, a lot.

Comment: I do understand that adding getters and setters would simply let the code know that there are new properties. But i think it would be a different case for *existing* code.

Comment: @Sikorski I simply prefer a `Map` for other specific reasons which I cannot disseminate publicly. It's a constraint, if you would consider it.

Comment: To clarify why I asked such a question: [1] Because I want to find out specifically how you can deal with nested casting - not only specifically to `Map`, but to any other possibly whatever that may involve static and indefinite casting. [2] I am ***absolutely aware*** of the other libraries. I just want to know for knowledge's sake as there are a lot of ways to accomplish something and the solution may vary from case to case or personal preference.

Comment: So now, I've learned how situations wherein using a `Map` can decrease maintainability. But also thanks to other people, I've also learned how using a `Map` does not necessarily decrease maintainability. Two different cases. I have learned 2 sides of a coin. I may use this in a future scenario that I am not aware of yet. Knowledge. Anyway, who would have thought that a million users didn't know how to escape `vim`. The guy who first asked that question on stackoverflow definitely didn't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some helper methods that may help things seem cleaner and more readable:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Map<String, Object> getMap(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return (Map<String, Object>)map.get(key);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static String getString(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return (String)map.get(key);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Integer geInteger(Map<String, Object> map, String key) {
    return (Integer)map.get(key);
}

// you can add more methods for Date, Long, and any other types you know you'll get
```

But you would have to *nest* the calls:

```
String attrValue = getString(getMap(getMap(map, id1), id2), attrName);
```

---

Or, if you want something more funky, add the above methods as instance methods to a map impl:

```
public class FunkyMap extends HashMap<String, Object> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public FunkyMap getNode(String key) {
        return (FunkyMap)get(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public String getString(String key) {
        return (String)get(key);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Integer geInteger(String key) {
        return (Integer)get(key);
    }

    // you can add more methods for Date, Long, and any other types you know you'll get
}
```

Deserialize into this class with your json library (you'll probably have to provide it with a factory method for the map class impl), then you can *chain* the calls more naturally:

```
String attrValue = map.getNode(id1).getNode(id2).getString(attrName);
```

The funky option is what I did for a company, and it worked a treat :)

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! I'll be opting for the funky one. Thanks!

Comment: Could you have possibly meant    `public FunkyMap<String, Object> getMap(String key) { return (FunkyMap<String, Object>)get(key); }`  ? As returning only a `Map` would not allow the chain calls you showed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know the depth of the JSON tree and if you worry about maintainability if new fields are added, I would recommend not to deserialize the full tree in a Map but instead use a low-level parser.

For example, if your JSON looks like the following:

```
{
    "id": {
        "id": {
            "id": {
                "id": 22.0
             }
         }
     }
}
```

You could write something like that to get the id using Jackson:

```
public Object getId(String json) throws JsonParseException, IOException
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(json);

    JsonNode id = root.get("id");
    while (id != null && id.isObject())
    {
        id = id.get("id");
    }

    //Cannot find a JsonNode for the id
    if (id == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //Convert id to either String or Long
    if (id.isTextual())
        return id.asText();

    if (id.isNumber())
        return id.asLong();

    return null;
}
```